# Group by a Dictionary in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I read data from an excel file, it is like this:

[image]

and I want to get the sum of Q1 and Q2 for each employee, so I create a dictionary, and want to group by based on that,

```
import pandas as pd

mb2 = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Desktop\\ml-1m\\工作簿1.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet3')
mapping = {'Jan':'Q1','Feb':'Q1','Mar':'Q1','Apr':'Q2','May':'Q2','Jun':'Q2'}
mb2.groupby(by=mapping,axis=1).sum()
```

[image]

How to show also the field Name? I try to do like this, but it didn't work:

```
mb2.groupby(by=(mapping,'Name'),axis=1).sum()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution is to save the resulting `DataFrame` in a new variable (`grouped_data` in the following code) and then assign the `Name` column to it using the original `DataFrame`:

```
grouped_data = mb2.groupby(by=mapping,axis=1).sum()
grouped_data['Name'] = mb2['Name']
print(grouped_data)
```

**EDIT:**
Another way of achieving the same result is to modify the `mapping` dictionary, adding a `"Name": "Name"` pair to it, and calling `mb2.groupby(by=mapping,axis=1).sum()` as before.

Comment: add a new column is workable, but adding a "Name": "Name" to mapping dic do not work,

Comment: Which version of pandas are you running? I tried the two solutions on version 0.19.1 and both worked.

Comment: is it like this : mapping = {'Name':'Name',Jan':'Q1','Feb':'Q1', 'Mar':'Q1','Apr':'Q2','May':'Q2','Jun':'Q2'}
mb2_new = mb2.groupby(by=mapping,axis=1).sum()

Comment: The following code in pandas 0.19.1 worked for me (with different numbers):

`mapping = {'Jan': 'Q1', 'Feb': 'Q1', 'Mar': 'Q1', 'Apr': 'Q2', 'May': 'Q2', 'Jun': 'Q2', 'Name': 'Name'}` ---

`df = pd.DataFrame([{'Name': 'Tony', 'Jan': 433, 'Feb': 692, 'Mar': 242, 'Apr': 1, 'May': 4, 'Jun': 11}, {'Name': 'Rafal', 'Jan': 263, 'Feb': 659, 'Mar': 483, 'Apr': 10, 'May': 6, 'Jun': 10}])` ---

`print(df.groupby(by=mapping, axis=1).sum())` --- If it doesn't work for you, you can use my other solution or @jezrael solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) first, then `groupby` and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = mb2.set_index('Name').groupby(by=mapping,axis=1).sum().reset_index()
print (df)
      Name    Q1    Q2
0     Tony  1367  1835
1    Rafal  1405  2574
2     John  1550  1409
3  Katrina  1555  1509
4    Kathy  1583  1491
5      Tom  1344  1874
```

Comment: Only one solution can to be accepted - it is up to you if my or another. Btw, groupby by dict is very nice;)